# Assigning a non-pointer to a pointer? (Subclassing a pointer type in C++?)

Tags: c++, function, templates, pointers, types

Recently I ran across some code which looked like this:

```
Foo<SomeType> member;
...
void SomeFunc(Bar* bar);
...
SomeFunc(member);
```

And I found it very confusing. Could someone explain what exactly is going on here?

How is `member` a valid `Bar*`?

Does `Foo<SomeType>` somehow subclass a pointer type?

Is this some property of templates? Is it still possible if `member` is a `Foo` instead of a `Foo<SomeType>`?

Comment: You need to provide the definition of `Foo<SomeType>` for a precise answer. Maybe it has an implicit conversion.

Comment: Are you sure there is no `void SomeFunc(Foo<SomeType> foo);` somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is member a valid Bar*?

One possibility is that `Foo<SomeType>` is convertible to `Bar*`. That can be achieved by having a [user-defined conversion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) in `Foo<SomeType>`. But I don't think the `Bar` pointer returned by such operation would be in any way meaningful. Perhaps, if `Foo<SomeType>` inherits `Bar` and the conversion operator returns `this` it might do something that makes sense, but that would be redundant and confusing.

> Does Foo somehow subclass a pointer type?

No. You cannot inherit fundamental types. Pointers are fundamental types.

> Is this some property of templates?

No.

> Is it still possible if member is a `Foo` instead of a `Foo<SomeType>`?

No. Instances of class templates are classes. `Foo<SomeType>` is a class. It's not `Foo`. Variables cannot have a template as a type.

Comment: "That can be achieved by having a converting constructor". It's the other way around. A converting constructor makes it convertible *from* the other type.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, converting constructors were exactly what I was looking for. To clarify the last question, I should have wrote "if `member` is some `Baz` instead of a `Foo<SomeType>`" to clarify that I was wondering that, if there was indeed a link between templates and this behavior, if it was possible without templates. In any case, thanks for the prompt reply!

Comment: @n.m. true, I originally made mistake that conversion was from `Bar*` to `Foo<SomeType>`, but when I fixed that, forgot that it affects my answer.

Comment: @Solicasus note that there was a mistake in my answer, which is now fixed. This can only be achieved with a conversion operator in `Foo<SomeType>`.